# Password policy on existing accounts not updated after making changes to login.defs

Tags: linux, login, pam

I have two old accounts that were previously set to defaults (no password expiration).  I updated `login.defs` and `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` for stricter password policy.  New accounts added to the system are subject to the new policy.  The two existing accounts still show no expiration date for the password.

```
chage -l some_existing_account
Last password change                    : Dec 04, 2013
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7


chage -l some_new_account
Last password change                    : Mar 31, 2015
Password expires                    : Apr 30, 2015
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 1
Maximum number of days between password change      : 30
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 14
```

How do I pull the existing accounts into the new policy?

Comment: There is no way to port `login.defs` to already create accounts. As far as i know, you will have to change your users manually.

Comment: Gotcha, `chage -m 1 -M 30 -W 14 some_existing_account` looks to be the only way of doing this.   I only have 2 existing users, but for systems with a bunch this could be easily scripted.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i was trying to say. You will have tu use specific commands to make the change :) . There is no `chage --apply-existing` for example that will automatically read `logins.def` and apply to all already created accounts.

Comment: @nwildner, feel free to add the info above as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no argument or option of `chage` that will apply all the changes made inside the `login.defs` fille to all the users.

You will have to manually edit user by user with this little snippet that you provided on the question comments:

`# chage -m 1 -M 30 -W 14 some_existing_account`

This could be a real pain when you have a multiserver environment, and using an Infrastructure automation tool like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), [Salt](http://saltstack.com/) or [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) is highly recommended. Take a look at this [Type Reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#user-attributes) and imagine the possibilities of bulk editing users ;)